# Is it ethical to contribute to a workshop one is organizing?

Tags: conference, ethics, etiquette, paper-submission, workshop

In computer science, workshops are often co-located with conferences. The workshop committee consists of roughly 3-5 chairs, who are organizing and chairing the workshop. Then there is a certain number (10+) of programm committee members. These are people who are responsible for reviewing submissions and spreading the word.

My question is: Is it okay if one of the chairs also submits a contribution to his/her own workshop or does this look weird?

I know, that for conferences this should be even stricter, but I am not sure if there is an established etiquette for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've helped organize several minisymposia (MS) at conferences that are built entirely out of them, and it's basically expected that we submit to our own MS. Out of three MS organizers and 8-10 expected speaking slots, 2-3 will be from the organizers. A few workshops I've attended at more prestigious conferences have been similar. The conference wants its events to be full, and if the subevents are peer reviewed, especially double-blind, then there's no possible conflict of interest in my view. Even for single-blind review or no review (abstract-only submission) as long as you don't review your own work, there's no problem and self-submission is practically expected in the fields I publish in.

Comment: which fields do you publish in?

Comment: Super/high performance computing and computational science, though less so of the latter these days (CFD was what my dissertation was about).

Comment: what would be your take on this, if the reviews are only single blind?

Comment: @beta, it's still fine. The organizers are still expected to attend and help the workshop by presenting at it. They don't get a pass or a leg up because the workshop review is single-blind and the reviewers know who they are. At best, they should get a full, thorough review since everyone knows they don't deserve a favorable bias.